# Topology GRE-esque question

Tags: general-topology

This isn't from the actual GRE, its from a mock GRE test provided by UChicago.

The problem goes as follows:

" A subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is *radially open* if for every $x\in U$ and every $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $x+sv\in U$ for every $s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Then the collection of radially open sets defines a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the radially open topology, and let $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard Euclidean topology. Consider the following statements about $X$.

I. $X$ is Hausdorff

II. $X$ is second countable.

III. The identity map $Y\mapsto X$ is continous.

Which of the above statements are true?

(A) I only

(B) II only

(C) I and II only

(D) I and III only

(E) II and III only."

The correct answer is:

> (A)

Now, for my attempt at this question, I can see that $X$ should be at least Hausdorff, and $X$ also contains more open sets than $Y$, so III is false. How would I go about answering II though?

The author gives the solution as: "Open $\implies$ radially open, and the restriction of $X$ to $S^1$ is discrete." I am not sure how to interpret the last part.

Comment: $x+sv\in u$ should be $x+sv\in U$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: this space is not regular and not first countable either, proofs could be found here: http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/MP/index_elemei/mp05-1/mp05-1-105-110.pdf Your question is similar to part (1) of the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336449

Comment: The fact that $X$ has more open sets than $Y$ already implies it's Hausdorff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The topology $X$ on ${\mathbb R}^2$ induces a subset topology $Z$ on $S^1$. Since every subset of $S^1$ is open in this topology, $Z$ is the discrete topology. Now if $X$ were second countable, so would be any subset topology since intersecting the countable basis elements for the original topology with the subset would give a countable basis for the subset topology. Thus $Z$ would have to be second countable. However, the discrete topology on $S^1$ is not second countable. Hence $X$ also must not be second countable.